# Only contact us email is being sent

Tags: magento-1.9, email, sales-order

I am new to Magento and I have installed Magento ver. 1.9.1.0 just couple of days ago. 
This is my problem:
My store is not sending any emails after placing the order, or commenting the order, changing status of it or any sales activity at all, as well as emails to friend. 
However when I submit an email through Contact Us form, this email is delivered.

Background:

- testmail.php is working I can send emails and they are delivered
- Configuration/General/Store Email Addresses are configured
- Configuration/Sales/Sales Emails are enabled
- I have even set Configuration/Advanced/System/Mail Sending Settings (No,smtp.xxx.xx,25,No), even though I believe this is not required
- I receive no error message. When I check the logs (had to create files manually myself), exception.log contains nothing related to mail, system.log is empty.
- I think this is not the problem, but now I am a bit paranoid, i run Magento no directly on the address www.example.com but on the www.example.com/apps/magento191_2

Any idea whats going on please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I remember Magento 1.9.1.0 did introduce a new feature regarding asyncron mail sending.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce19-later-release-notes

> It's more important than ever for you to configure a Magento cron job. In addition to indexing and other core functions, all Magento e-mails (including order confirmation and transactional) are now queued and sent according to your configured cron schedule.

So its very likely, you did not setup your cronjob yet.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I have checked the official documentation and User Guide for Magento 1.9.1 as well and cron is not even mentioned in the email setup procedure.

Comment: Anyway I have created the Cron. As a Cron link I put http://mymagento.com/cron.php  - Hope this is OK?

Comment: as long as you regularly call it.